# How to write below mysql query using Entity Framework with Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

```
SELECT
`Distinct1`.`UserId`, 
`Distinct1`.`FirstName`, 
`Distinct1`.`LastName`, 
`Distinct1`.`EmailAddress`, 

FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
`Extent2`.`UserId`, 
`Extent2`.`FirstName`, 
`Extent2`.`LastName`, 
`Extent2`.`EmailAddress`, 

    FROM `AssistantTo` AS `Extent1` 
    INNER JOIN `User` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`AssistantId` = `Extent2`.`UserId`
    INNER JOIN `CustomTagUser` as `Extent3` ON `Extent3`.`UserId` = `Extent2`.`UserId`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`OwnerId` = 274 AND `Extent3`.`CustomTagId` = 114
 ) AS `Distinct1`
```

This is my Table structure :

[image]

I tried using following query but it is giving me error.

```
 var assistants =
                    dbContext.AssistantsTo
                        .Include(x => x.Assistant)
                        .Include(x => x.Assistant.CustomTagUser)
                        .Where(at =>
                            at.OwnerId == currentUser.UserId
                            && (at.Assistant.CustomTagUser.Count(y => y.CustomTagId == filter) > 0)
                            )
                        .Select(at => at.Assistant)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

Error : {"Unknown column 'Extent1.AssistantId' in 'where clause'"}

Basically I have issue with giving filter for

```
`Extent3`.`CustomTagId` = 114
```

I think we can use any() but I have bad experience using any() with large data & mysql.

Model classes

```
public class AssistantTo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AssistantToId { get; set; }
        public int AssistantId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AssistantId")]
        public virtual User Assistant { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
        public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomTagUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomTagUserId { get; set; }
        public int CustomTagId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomTagId")]
        public virtual CustomTags CustomTags { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }


[Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        .....   
        public ICollection<CustomTagUser> CustomTagUser { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

> Basically I have main problem with applying this part in EF

```
AND Extent3.CustomTagId = 114
```

Comment: your table structure doesn't match with the query. Where is `Distinct1` && `Extent2` tables ?????

Comment: it's an alias , Which is generated by EF. See the query carefully & you will get idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var assistants =
                    dbContext.AssistantsTo
                        .Include(x => x.Assistant)
                        .Include(x => x.Assistant.CustomTagUser)
                        .Where(at =>
                            at.OwnerId == currentUser.UserId && 
                            (                               
                                at.Assistant.CustomTagUser.Select(x => x.CustomTagId).Contains(filter)
                            )
                        .Select(at => at.Assistant)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

try this one...